# create custom server or user button

Tags: .net, custom-controls, custom-server-controls

I have a very specific problem. I have a user control (code below) That needs to act like a button. I have researched into writting a custom server control but I think that is kind've over kill. The other option i have come accross is having the div tag fire a javascript onclick and that would trigger an asp:button click event. But I also feel that is also hacky.

**The solution I am looking for is that whenever the user control is clicked it will fire a onClick event (acting like a normal button, except with my desired markup).**

(user control code) there is css styling for the font, that shouldn't impact the issue.

```
  <div style="border:2px solid black; background-color:white" >
    <div>
      <asp:Label ID="lblMeetingCityState" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>'></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <asp:Label ID="lblMeetingDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MeetingDate") %>'></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <asp:Label ID="lblMeetingSite" runat='server' Text='<%# Eval("Location") %>'></asp:Label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

code behind to raise event on click

```
<System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSetAttribute(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")> _
Partial Public Class MeetingButton
  Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
  Implements System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler

  Public Event Click As EventHandler

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

  End Sub

  Protected Overridable Sub OnClick(ByVal E As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent Click(Me, E)
  End Sub

  Public Sub RaisePostBackEvent(ByVal eventArgument As String) _
         Implements IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent

    OnClick(New EventArgs())
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Each of the answers below have only pointed me in th right direction, if you are reading this please take a minute to help out. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An asp:linkbutton seems to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

[IPostBackEventHandler Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.aspx) will allow you to do this. Basically in the code behind of your user control add the following:

```
public class MyUserControl: Control, IPostBackEventHandler {

      // Defines the Click event.
      public event EventHandler Click;

      //Invoke delegates registered with the Click event.
      protected virtual void OnClick(EventArgs e) {

         if (Click != null) {
            Click(this, e);
         }   
      }


      // Define the method of IPostBackEventHandler that raises change events.
      public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument){

         OnClick(new EventArgs());
      }

}
```

Comment: I have converted this to vb and put it in the codebehind of my user control, but I do not seem able to raiseThePostback event

Comment: do I need to change my user control to be a custom server control to get this to work?

Comment: I also cannot trigger the post back unless i put an input type into the markup or from codebehind. I want the input type to be the entire first level div. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: There are 2 ways to generate a postback in ASP.NET, firstly there is the standard input type="submit" way, the second one is use the javascript method __doPostBack();

Answer (score 1):

In your usercontrol codebehind, use the [ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112.aspx) method.